# How to find and use a helper method from String

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to know how to find and use a helper method, when I have the name of the helper in a string format.

I am writing an engine, and in the initializer file, users can specify the current_user_helper as such:

```
MyEngine.current_user_helper = "current_user"
```

I would like to do something with this in the controller. For instance, the code below tries to create a Post for the logged in user.

```
MyEngine.current_user_helper.posts.new(post_params)
```

Yet, this code does not work because `MyEngine.current_user_helper` is a string. Apparently, Rails will throw an error when I try:

```
MyEngine.current_user_helper = current_user
```

without the quotation marks.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `send` to call a method from a string or symbol. `send` is available on all descendants of Object.

`send(MyEngine.current_user_helper).posts.new`

Comment: That is pretty spot on. What am I calling the `send` on? If I am doing this in a controller, is it the controller itself, and that is a descendant of `Object`?